# convert kml to gpx programmatically or with a command

Tags: python, gdal, kml, ogr2ogr, gpx

I have a KML file I downloaded from Google Maps "My Maps". This KML has many layers, each layer with many POIs.
I would like to convert the KML with tools like `ogr2ogr` from the `GDAL` library or some python scripts, but I find it very hard.

So far:

- `ogr2ogr -f GPX my_file.gpx my_file.kml`

  - gives `ERROR 6: Cannot create GPX layer MY_LAYER_XYZ with unknown geometry type`
- `ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -f GPX my_file.gpx my_file.kml`

  - gives many errors on various fields (which I guess come from how Google builds the KML) similar to `ERROR 6: Field of name 'description' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.`
  - then it also gives `ERROR 1: Features without geometry or with non-ponctual geometries not supported by GPX writer in waypoints layer.
    ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 2 from layer MY_LAYER_XYZ.`
- `ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES  my_file.gpx my_file.kml`

  - gives `ERROR 1: Features without geometry or with non-ponctual geometries not supported by GPX writer in waypoints layer.
    ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 2 from layer MY_LAYER_XYZ.`
- `ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES -lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES my_file.gpx my_file.kml`

  - gives `ERROR 1: Features without geometry or with non-ponctual geometries not supported by GPX writer in waypoints layer.
    ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 2 from layer MY_LAYER_XYZ.`

I've tried this python script `kml2gpx.py` at https://gist.github.com/timabell/8791116 which looking at the code should iterate through the KML processing it as "normal XML" content (using stuff like `import xml.sax`), but the output does not contain any of the POIs in the orginal KML.

I am not familiar with the KML and the GPX standard, I just wished there was a handy script to convert one to the other. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Have you tried a two-step conversion?  KML -> GeoJSON -> GPX?  Maybe inspecting the GeoJSON would give you a better idea about the structure and help guide the conversion to GPX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've ended up using `gpsbabel` which provides a GUI along with the command.

On ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo apt-get install gpsbabel-gui
```

This will install the command `gpsbabel` as well.

You can follow the GUI settings, it's easy, in my case I removed all the extra options to convert tracks and routes (I was interested only in waypoints).
Otherwise the command is the following one:

```
gpsbabel -w -i kml -f <INPUT_FILE_NAME.kml> -o gpx -F <OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.gpx>
```

Comment: To convert the KML to a CSV file: `gpsbabel -w -i kml -f <INPUT_FILE_NAME.kml> -o unicsv,grid=4 -F <OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.gpx>` So then you could print to PDF / paper the notes you may have in the popup windows of the POIs in your map on Google My Maps

Answer (score 2):

You could try using GPSBabel. It does a great job of converting between GPS formats, including GPX and KML.  It's available as a desktop application, and as a commandline tool. More info on support for various operating systems is available in the documentation, here: https://www.gpsbabel.org/osnotes.html