# How to convert KML file to GPX or GNX?

Tags: gpx

I have to select manually the areas of extraction from SAS Planet

Comment: Can you export them to KML file in ArcGIS and then to GPX or GNX ?  or Have you seen this ? https://esri.jiveon.com/ideas/10483

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert kml to gpx programmatically or with a command](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253222/convert-kml-to-gpx-programmatically-or-with-a-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPSUtility (www.gpsu.co.uk) will convert KML tracks and routes to GPX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GPSBabel to convert from KML to GPX. It's free and easy to use, and available here: https://www.gpsbabel.org/

A usage example can be found [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7369/convert-kml-to-gpx-w-gpsbabel).

You can also convert them with [ogr2ogr](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), but I found GPSBabel to be a bit easier to use.